# How to solve AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'py_func'

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

```
def aurocc(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.py_func(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred))

adam = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=[aurocc])
model.fit(inputs,labels,validation_split=0.33,epochs=10,verbose=1,callbacks=callbacks)
```

```
AttributeError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:830 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:813 run_step  *
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py:775 train_step  *
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:457 update_state  *
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:169 decorated  *
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:155 update_state_fn  *
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/metrics.py:641 update_state  *
        matches = ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    <ipython-input-46-e104431197fe>:2 aurocc  *
        return tf.py_func(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred))

    AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.compat.v2' has no attribute 'py_func'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 0):

This name `tf.compat.v1.py_func` was deprecated and removed in TF2, but you can use `tf.numpy_function` instead.

Before:(It shows warning in Tensorflow 2.x)

```
def fn_using_numpy(x):
  x[0] = 0.
  return x
tf.compat.v1.py_func(fn_using_numpy, inp=[tf.constant([1., 2.])],
    Tout=tf.float32, stateful=False)
```

Output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-4-2c02087a506a>:5: py_func (from tensorflow.python.ops.script_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
tf.py_func is deprecated in TF V2. Instead, there are two
    options available in V2.
    - tf.py_function takes a python function which manipulates tf eager
    tensors instead of numpy arrays. It's easy to convert a tf eager tensor to
    an ndarray (just call tensor.numpy()) but having access to eager tensors
    means `tf.py_function`s can use accelerators such as GPUs as well as
    being differentiable using a gradient tape.
    - tf.numpy_function maintains the semantics of the deprecated tf.py_func
    (it is not differentiable, and manipulates numpy arrays). It drops the
    stateful argument making all functions stateful.
    
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 2.], dtype=float32)>
```

**After:**

```
tf.numpy_function(fn_using_numpy, inp=[tf.constant([1., 2.])],
    Tout=tf.float32)
```

**Output:**

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0., 2.], dtype=float32)>
```

For more details, refer this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/py_func).